# SUM of two table column base on another column value and SUBTRACT and join tables

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

Table Name EmployeeInformation

```
EmployeeID EmployeeFirstName EmployeeLastName
    1             |John      |Baker
    2             |Carl      |Lennon
    3             |Marion    |Herbert
```

Table Name PeriodInformation

```
PeriodID PeriodStart PeriodEnd
    1   |1/1/14      |12/30/14
    2   |1/1/15      |12/30/15
```

Table Name LeaveType

```
LeaveTypeID LeaveTypeName
     1      |Annual Leave
     2      |Sick Leave
```

Table Name LeaveEntitlment

```
SNO LeaveTypeID PeriodID EmployeeID LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber
 1   |     1   |    1    |     1   |          10
 2   |     1   |    1    |     1   |          15
 3   |     2   |    1    |     1   |          15
 4   |     2   |    2    |     1   |           5
 5   |     1   |    2    |     2   |          10    
 6   |     1   |    2    |     2   |          10
 7   |     1   |    2    |     2   |          15
 8   |     2   |    2    |     2   |          15
 9   |     2   |    2    |     2   |           5
 10  |     1   |    1    |     2   |          10
```

Table Name AssigneLeave

```
SNO LeaveTypeID PeriodID EmployeeID AssignedLeaveDaysNumber
 1   |     1   |    1    |     1    |          10
 2   |     1   |    1    |     1    |          10
 3   |     2   |    1    |     1    |           5
 4   |     2   |    2    |     1    |           5
 5   |     1   |    2    |     2    |           2    
 6   |     1   |    2    |     2    |           3
 7   |     1   |    2    |     2    |           4
 8   |     2   |    2    |     2    |           8
 9   |     2   |    2    |     2    |           5
 10  |     1   |    1    |     2    |           9
```

I want a query to join all this tables based on `EmployeeID`, `PeriodID` and 
`LeaveTypeID`

sum of `LeaveEntitlement.LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber` based on `LeaveTypeID` AS `EntitleAnnaul` and AS `EntitleSick`
and sum `AssignedLeave.AssignedLeaveDaysNumber` based on `LeaveTypeID`  AS `AssignedAnnaul` and AS `AssignedSick`
and subtract `EntitleAnnaul` from `AssignedAnnual` based on `LeaveTypeID`  AS `AnnualBalance`
and subtract `EntitleSick` from `AssignedSick` based on `LeaveTypeID`  AS `SickBalance`

the query should show the following columns:

```
EmployeeID, 
EmployeeFirstName, 
EmployeeLastName, 
PeriodID, 
PeriodStart, 
PeriodEnd, 
EntitleAnnual, 
AssignedAnnual, 
AnnualBalance, 
EntitleSick, 
AssignedSick, 
SickBalance
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query (aggregation using group by in sub query and then do calculation in outer query), normal join is used assuming that data is present in all tables, if not then you will have to modify query to use left/right outer join

```
select
    SubQry.EmployeeID, 
    SubQry.EmployeeFirstName, 
    SubQry.EmployeeLastName, 
    SubQry.PeriodID, 
    SubQry.PeriodStart, 
    SubQry.PeriodEnd, 
    SubQry.EntitleAnnual, 
    SubQry.AssignedAnnual, 
    (SubQry.EntitleAnnual-SubQry.AssignedAnnual) as AnnualBalance, 
    SubQry.EntitleSick, 
    SubQry.AssignedSick, 
    (SubQry.EntitleSick-SubQry.AssignedSick) as SickBalance
From 
(
Select
    ei.EmployeeID,
    ei.EmployeeFirstName ,
    ei.EmployeeLastName,
    pi.PeriodID, 
    pi.PeriodStart, 
    pi.PeriodEnd, 
    Sum( Case when lt.LeaveTypeID = 1 Then le.LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber Else 0 End ) as EntitleAnnual, 
    Sum( Case when lt.LeaveTypeID = 1 Then al.AssignedLeaveDaysNumber Else 0 End ) as AssignedAnnual, 
    Sum( Case when lt.LeaveTypeID = 2 Then le.LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber Else 0 End ) as EntitleSick, 
    Sum( Case when lt.LeaveTypeID = 2 Then al.AssignedLeaveDaysNumber Else 0 End ) as AssignedSick
From ( select EmployeeID,LeaveTypeID,PeriodID,sum(LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber) as LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber from LeaveEntitlment group by EmployeeID,LeaveTypeID,PeriodID ) le 
join ( select EmployeeID,LeaveTypeID,PeriodID,sum(AssignedLeaveDaysNumber) as AssignedLeaveDaysNumber from AssigneLeave group by EmployeeID,LeaveTypeID,PeriodID )  al on le.EmployeeID = al.EmployeeID and le.LeaveTypeID = al.LeaveTypeID and le.PeriodID = al.PeriodID
join EmployeeInformation ei on ei.EmployeeID = le.EmployeeID
join PeriodInformation pi on pi.PeriodID = le.PeriodID 
join LeaveType lt on lt.LeaveTypeID = le.LeaveTypeID
group by ei.EmployeeID,ei.EmployeeFirstName,ei.EmployeeLastName,pi.PeriodID,pi.PeriodStart,pi.PeriodEnd
) SubQry
```

Comment: Thanks narendra I did the same what you instructed but when I execute the result is wrong.

Comment: for example in EntitleAnnual it should retrieve a sum of 65 but it retrieves 325 and AssignedAnnual it should retrieve a sum of 59 but it retrieves 118  and in two other columns as well. I dont know what is the problem?

Comment: Any solution Mr.  Narendra?

Comment: Just now saw that your tables have duplicates, modified query in answer to handle it, pls try again it will give expected results

Comment: this is working correct but the problem is that when the column AssignedLeaveDaysNumber isnull it does not retrieve the sum of LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber as well. meaning that AssignedLeaveDaysNumber rows are leaser than the LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber that is why it does not retrieve the sum of LeaveEntitlementDaysNumber completely.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer I assumed all data is present, you can modify the query accordingly putting nvl check and left other join

Comment: Thanks it worked, just added left for the first join.